# run mitmproxy-node inside of a Docker container?

Tags: python, node.js, docker, mitmproxy

Pls note that the Docker container is run inside a Jenkins pipeline. I am trying to run a specific npm package mitmproxy-node on/in a Docker container, it has a dependency on the python mitmproxy package. I think that I need to have the python dep inside of the node container so that the node code can find and run/instantiate the mitmproxy during runtime(it is being turned on as a runtime process.env )

How do I construct/fix a Dockerfile to build the container so that the node container, where the test.runner exists knows/can use the python mitmproxy code ?

I have some thing like this.

```
FROM node:14.15-buster

COPY .package*.json .package*.json
COPY .npmrc .npmrc

is it here? RUN apt-get install python ?
RUN npm install

COPY . . 
CMD ("npm", "test")
```

When trying to instantiate mitmproxy, it throws an error

```
Error in beforeSession: 
Error: mitmdump, which is an executable that ships with mitmproxy, is not on your PATH. 
Please ensure that you can run mitmdump --version successfully from your command line.
```

I am pretty new when it comes to Docker so your help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need node in the mix? I would recommend to just use https://hub.docker.com/r/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/.

Comment: @MaximilianHils the entire test framework is built in node/typescript. Hub isn't an option, as the container is built by a Jenkins job

Comment: Ah, I see. Well in that case you want to `apt install python3` and then go on from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the full dockerfile that got me to where I am goin.

```
FROM node:14.15.0-buster
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update || : && apt-get install python3 -y -V
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/bin/python3"

RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y -V
RUN pip3 install mitmproxy
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/bin/mitmproxy"

ARG NPM_TOKEN

COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "test"]
```